# Is it possible to upload an already working local Laravel app to the cloud without installing Laravel there?

Tags: laravel, dns, cloud

Is it possible to simply upload an already working app as well as the required folders and files that already work well in my local server to the cloud
without installing laravel there ? I use Webuzo panel to manage domain, apache services, mysql service, etc as well as other tasks.

Of course, I have setup my domain and its path, including htaccess file as well as modifying the index.php file.
The index.php is executed, so is my main controller class, as some simple echo statements were dislayed on the browser.
So to that point, I assume my route/request was well served by Laravel.
But I had a problem with the return or response of my controllers.

Even in a simple routing case like the following, it didn't run as expected :

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
   echo "Test again";
   return 'Trouble shooting ...';
   // return response('Test in cloud', 200)
   //   ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');    
});
```

The echo statement was executed, as its output was displayed on the browser. But the return statement didn't produce anything.
But there are no errors displayed on the browser which indicated failure.

Did I miss some necessary things in the steps I have done ?
Does this mean that I have to install Laravel on my domain in the cloud ?

Comment: Why not `php artisan down` ?

Comment: Not sure why you have this issue. I can tell you this: done this once, never again. It took 8 hours to find out that some config settings were wrong and the .env file had some missing settings. It won't show you any error. But a blank page is not really what you want to see neither. My advice: shut it down at 2 am, get everything out and install laravel as you would do on any server. Just check if the server requirements are what laravel and your setup needs. In half an hour it's done. If something goes wrong Lex, you won't have any idea what it is. Just like now. Make sure of config and .env.

Comment: STA and @Dimitri : Thanks for quick responses. Based on your advice, it means that I still need to install Laravel to make sure my app will work. That will be the last resort if by current way, i.e without installing Laravel, doesn't work. I have verified that .env and config\app.php are set correctly. If not, then the route/end point won't be reached at all or the echo statement won't be executed. I don't see any explanation in Laravel documentation regarding this issue. So it seems that I still need to install Laravel in the domain.

Comment: You could of course install your laravel app in a completely separate map `~/repositories/your-laravel-app` and switch it over in the htaccess file. This is a good practice, especially if you are using github as the master source. This way you can easily revert if something goes terribly wrong.

Comment: @Dimitri : Thanks for your reply. Actually my app is of a kind that will be used/accessed from multi domain. I am considering different ways to accomplish it. But I am afraid it will be difficult to revert to the initial working state. For example, there is a package : https://github.com/gecche/laravel-multidomain I am still considering it, but I won't rush on using it for some reasons. Have you ever tried that package ?

Comment: @Dimitri : To be clear, actually I already have a primary domain in the same host/VPS. I have installed Laravel 5.8 in that domain; the app have been working well there. Recently I have added an addon domain on which I am doing experiment to see whether I can simply upload files and folders without installing Laravel on that new domain.